# How to override Backspace key function in document as in Google

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends I was making a calculator like project so It is a full webpage that displays my calculator. For inputs from keyboard all other keys worked. And I also want to use backspace key to do [del] command as in calculator. But it always goes to Backward visited site. Here's my code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
 var e=window.event || e
var keyunicode=e.charCode || e.keyCode
if(keyunicode>=40 && keyunicode<=57 && keyunicode!=44)
{
    //call a function [worked]
}
else if(keyunicode==61)
{
// call another function worked.
}
else if(keyunicode==8)
{
e.preventDefault();
delete_last();

return false;
}

});
```

Please help. I tried in chrome..

Comment: Browser keyboard shortcuts always win. Keys are only sent to the page after the browser has decided it has no use for them. This is by design. Otherwise, a nefarious website could hijack all kinds of user interaction.

Comment: Then how am I able to override F5 to refresh an iframe instead of the window? :p

Comment: You should not use `var e`, when you have already declared the variable in the formal function parameters. If you want to overwrite thevariable, just omit `var`. Furthermore, jQuery already deals with browser-specific implementations, and normalizes the event object. The first two lines in your function can be replaced with `var keyunicode = e.which`.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `08`. According to microsoft there is a leading `0` you are missing [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisPratt: That's not entirely true. Most browser shortcuts can be overwritten (including backspace). Test [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) (make a tick on prevent keydown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `keydown` listener to catch <kbd>backspace</kbd>. `keypress` is meant for character keys. `keydown` is useful for functional keys.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 8) {
    //your custom action here
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does only support the `keypress` event for some keys and backspace is not among these. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606 for details.

React to `keydown` and call `preventDefault` on the event to see an effect in Chrome, too.

Comment: I got it. Google chrome is bad for it.. If any trick suggestion for chrome please suggest.

Comment: The suggestion is to use `keydown` instead of `keypress`. I would not say Chrome is bad for it: Key events have not been standardized and the vendors chose different implementations. The Chrome developers wanted to match Microsoft's way (see comment 5 and 11 of the linked bug). This way is now also proposed in an [event's specification draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order). In my opinion Mozilla's way is more logical and it would've been better if it was even more based on the physical meaning of words such as down (no repetitions contradictory to draft).